Computation of the Rings $H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})$
I'm studying Fomenko-Fuchs lecture 26.2 and I'm studying the following Theorem at page 371:
Theorem.
$$
\text{n odd} \implies H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})=\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}}(x), \text{dim}x=n; 
$$
$$ 
\text{n even} \implies H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}[x], \text{dim}x=n.
$$
during their proof they say:

Moreover, there exist such nonzero $y \in H^{n-1}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n-1) ; \mathbb{Q})=E_2^{0, n-1}=E_n^{0, n-1}$ and $x_k \in H^{k n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})=E_2^{k n, 0}=E_n^{k n, 0}(k=1,2,3, \ldots)$ that $d_n(y)=$ $x_1, d_n\left(y x_1\right)=x_2$, and so on (see Fig. 101, right). But then
$$
x_k=d_n\left(y x_{k-1}\right)=d_n(y) x_{k-1}=x_1 x_{k-1},
$$
from which $x_k=x_1^k$. This establishes an isomorphism between the rings $H^*(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathbb{Q}\left[x_1\right]$

I got three doubts:

I think I'm confused with their notation: what are "$yx_k$" and "$d_n(y)x_{k-1}$"?
$y \in H^{n-1}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n-1);\mathbb{Q})$ , $d_n^{0,n-1}(y) \in H^{n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})$ and $x_k \in H^{k n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})$, so I suppose that $yx_k:=x_k \otimes y \in H^{kn}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})\otimes H^{n-1}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n-1) ; \mathbb{Q}) = E_n^{kn,n-1}$ and $d_n(y)x_{k-1}:= d_n^{0,n-1}(y) \smile x_{k-1} \in H^{n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q}) \smile H^{(k-1) n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q}) \subseteq H^{k n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})$
Is this correct?

Why do those elements $y$ and $x_k$ exist? This is my attempt: $d_n^{kn,n-1}$ are isomorphism, so if $y$ is a generator of $H^{n-1}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n-1);\mathbb{Q})$ then $d_n^{0,n-1}(y)$ is a generator of $H^{n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})$. Let's call it $x_1$. But then $yx_1:=x_1 \otimes y$ is a generator of $H^{n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})\otimes H^{n-1}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n-1) ; \mathbb{Q}) = E_n^{n,n-1}$, so $d_n^{n,n-1}(yx_1)$ is a generator of $H^{2n}(K(\mathbb{Z}, n) ; \mathbb{Q})$ that we call $x_2$. Inductively we have $d_n^{kn,n-1}(yx_k)=x_{k+1}$.
Is this correct?

Why is it true that
$$d_n(yx_{k-1})=d_n(y)x_{k-1}$$
or in other words, why is it true that
$$d_n^{kn,n-1}(x_{k-1}\otimes y)=d_n^{0,n-1}(y) \smile x_{k-1}$$



Please tell us at least what spectral sequences you're/Fomenko-Fuchs are considering here. I do think your interpretation for the first bullet point is essentially correct; when the $E_2$-page is a tensor product people sometimes omit the $\otimes$ between elements. For the last point, you should get $d_n(y x_{k - 1}) = d_n(y) x_{k - 1} \pm y d_n(x_{k - 1})$ since the differentials are derivations, but if I guessed the correct  sequence then $d_n(x_{k - 1})$ is 0 for degree reasons: the $x_{k -1}$ live on the horizontal axis and the differentials run off the page.
